# How to deploy Publish site to GitHub Pages

Tags: swift, macos, github-pages, publish

I'm developing a static site using [John Sundell's Publish](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish) framework.  I've got the site mostly working, and I want to deploy it to my GitHub Pages repo.  Publish includes a publishing step called `.deploy(using: .gitHub("githubusername/githubusername.github.io", useSSH: false))` (to be clear, I did use my actual username).  However, when I ran it the first time I received a pop-up authentication window, which I entered and it said incorrect password.  Since then, whenever I run it, it just shows an error and doesn't offer any password window:

```
publish deploy
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Publish encountered an error:
[step] Deploy using Git (https://github.com/githubusername/githubusername.github.io.git)
[path] GitDeploy
[info] Failed to create folder: file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.8.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 200
/bin/bash: line 1:  9577 Illegal instruction: 4  swift run RyanBudishSite --deploy
❌ ShellOut encountered an error
Status code: 132
Message: "Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Publish encountered an error:
[step] Deploy using Git (https://github.com/githubusername/githubusername.github.io.git)
[path] GitDeploy
[info] Failed to create folder: file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.8.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 200
/bin/bash: line 1:  9577 Illegal instruction: 4  swift run RyanBudishSite --deploy"
Output: ""
```

Does anyone have any experience getting Publish to deploy to GitHub Pages?  Any tips/ideas/suggestions would be very useful

Comment: did you find a solution? This happens to me just the second time I try to deploy with a similar error: [path] GitDeploy
[info] Failed to create folder: file Swift/ErrorType.swift, line 200
/bin/bash: line 1: 73478 Illegal instruction: 4  swift run Publishdavid --deploy"
Output: ""   --- Strangely in a new repository all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed my site in GutHub Pages using the built in `.gitHub` publishing step.

To deploy to GitHub Pages, Publish clones your `githubusername/githubusername.github.io` project into `<YourProjcet>/.publish/GitDeploy`. I am new to Swift and Publish, but by the looks of your error, it was unable to create the `GitDeploy` folder or clone your pages project there.

Run `deploy` once, after it fails go to the above location and see what is wrong. If there's some issue with pushing/fetching the GitHub Pages repo, resolve it manually and try running the `publish deploy` again.

If `GitDeploy` folder is not created, maybe creating one manually will fix it.

Comment: I tried that and it worked at once but then I got [path] GitDeploy
[info] Failed to create folder: file Swift/ErrorType.swift, line 200
/bin/bash: line 1: 73478 Illegal instruction: 4  swift run Publishdavid --deploy"
Output: ""